# Firebase creating empty users, even though the Auth feature requires email

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's auth feature and sometimes I see empty users in the console. This brings issues to some users because instead of logging into their main account (and using their UID to fetch their user data in a users reference), log into that empty account with a UID which is not theirs.

Not sure exactly how that can happen, but it seems like this could be a bug on Firebase's side, because a successful Auth should have at least 1 provider...

Any ideas about such issue and how I could fix it from my side if possible?

Ps.: Is that how "signInAnonymously" would create anonymous accounts?

[image: Firebase creating empty users]

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended behavior when you [authenticate with Firebase anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

`signInAnonymously()` method signs in the user anonymously without requiring any credential and creates a new account in your Firebase Authentication system, except in the case where there was already an anonymous user signed in into the app.

See [FirebaseAuth.signInAnonymously](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInAnonymously()) class reference for more details.

Comment: In my case, Anonymous users are not enabled in the providers settings nor do we create any in our codebase.